# Filter for static file middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, middleware

Is there a way to intercept the request before it got serve, so I can edit a picture or create dynamic pdf on demand? I tried using MapArea and redirect the request to a controller, but when I use staticfiles middleware, it catch the request, and my controller wont handle the request.

Answer (score 2):

If your static files does not exist and you want generate them on-thy-fly - it's better to create your own middelware and register it before `UseStaticFiles`.

If files exist, but you want "slightly" modify response (for different users for example) - you may use `OnPrepareResponse` handler in static file options:

```
var staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
    {
        var fn = context.File.Name.ToLowerInvariant();
        if (fn.EndsWith(".pdf"))
        {
            SomeService.LogPdfDownload(context.Context.Response);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=15552000"); // 180 days
        }
    }
};

app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
```

[From docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfileoptions#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Builder_StaticFileOptions_OnPrepareResponse): `OnPrepareResponse` is called after the status code and headers have been set, but before the body has been written

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to intercept the request before it got serve

Yes. You can write your own middleware and add it to IApplicationBuilder before you call UseStaticFiles. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware#ordering

See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing. You may also be able to solve this problem by writing routes instead of middleware.